# AngularJS Navigation between controller Index pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to AngularJs . I have 2 controllers in my MVC3 application with corresponding index pages.

Let's say the first controller is `LoginController` and the other one is `DashboardController`.

Each index page has different layouts. I want to navigate to `DashboardController`  index.cshtml page if login is successful. How can I navigate to `DashboardController` index page from the current `LoginController` index page with the help of angularjs `$routeprovider`?

**app.js**

```
angular.module('testModule', ['ngRoute'])
.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
$scope.Authenticate = function () {
    $scope.Login.UserId = 2;
    $scope.Login.RoleId = 501;
    $scope.Login.AcctPassword = 'sss';
    var postform = JSON.stringify($scope.Login);
    if ($scope.Login.Username != '') {

        $http.post('/Login/Authenticate', postform).success(function (data) {
            if (data.Status == false) {
                alert(data.errorMessage);
            }
            else {
                $location.path("/Dashboard");
            }
        });
    }
};
})
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
   .when('/', {templateUrl: '/Login/Index.cshtml',controller: 'LoginController'  })
   .when('/Temp', {templateUrl: '/Login/TempView.cshtml',controller: 'LoginController' })
   .when('/Dashboard', { templateUrl: '/Dashboard/Listing', controller: 'DashboardController' })
   .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });


    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); //Remove the '#' from URL.
  } ]);
```

The Dashboard is an Area in my Project. Listing is the controller in Dashboard Area with an index.cshtml page .

Comment: Usually in an MVC project you would be loading an action from a controller and NOT a `.cshtml` file, you may need to look at your templateUrl's and do something like:  `/Login/Index`, `/Login/Temp`, `/Dashboard/Listing` where those call actions that are returning your views.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather inject `$window` into your `LoginController`.
You could then define this method in the controller :

```
$scope.go = function(path = "#/Dashboard/") {
  return $window.location = path;
};
```

Then use it in your template:

```
<ANY ng-click="go()"/>
<ANY ng-click="go('#/Temp/')"/>
```

Comment: Routing will not help in this cases??

Comment: @AbinDavis I don't understand your question. You could just a verification of the token to route if login is successful but it's the role of the back-end to no serve resources if user cannot access it.